# Building Convolutional Neural Network using large images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I understand reating convolutional nerural network for 32 x 32 x 3 image, but i am planning to use larger image with different pixels. How can I reduce the image size to the required size ? does the pixel reduction impact accuracy in tensor flow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically there is no limit on the size of images being fed into a CNN. The most significant problem with larger image sizes is the increased memory footprint, especially with large batches. Moreover, you would need to use more convolutional layers to down sample the input image. Downsizing an image is a possibility of course, but you will lose discriminative information, naturally. For downsampling you can use scipy's `scipy.misc.imresize`.